# How do you parse "futurum est" in Matthew 2:13?

Tags: verbs, grammar-identification, translation-explanation, vulgata

I'm a little confused about a verse in Matthew 2 of the Vulgate Bible.

> Futurum est enim ut Herodes quærat puerum ad perdendum eum.
>   ([Matthew 2:13](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=matthew+2%3A13&version=VULGATE))

[Douay-Rheims](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=matthew+2%3A13&version=DRA) translates this as, "For it will come to pass that Herod will seek the child to destroy him."

But how would you classify the verb phrase "Futurum est"?

To me it looks like perfect passive indicative, but that wouldn't fit the translation.

Even though I know how Douay-Rheims translated it, I'm struggling to figure out the rules they used to arrive at their translation. I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Futurum est* is a future active periphrastic form. It is built from *futurum*, the future active participle of *sum* (here in the neuter), which by itself means "going to be, about to be". With the addition of *est*, it means "It is going to be", or in the translation you quote, "It will come to pass".

Comment: @C.M.Weimer: Hello! Why not?

Comment: @C.M.Weimer Semantically that's arguable, but morphologically *futurum* is an active form; the OP was parsing it as a perfect passive, so I thought it was important to correct.

Comment: @TKR Thank you for the concise and helpful answer.

Comment: @Cerberus I suspect that what C.M. Weimer means is that *esse* is neither active nor passive but copulative.

Comment: @JoelDerfner: But copulae are active...

Comment: @Cerberus Yes—that's what I took C.M. Weimer's "really" to mean.

Comment: @JoelDerfner: Well, I think I disagree with him here. I don't see why it shouldn't be active. Its morphology is active. What would semantics have to do with it?

Comment: @C.M.Weimer: It has no passive form, like several other intransitive verbs? Just as some other verbs have practically no active forms.

Answer (score 5):

The Greek original has μέλλει γὰρ Ἡρῴδης ζητεῖν τὸ παιδίον τοῦ ἀπολέσαι αὐτό ("Herod is on the point of seeking the child in order to destroy him"). Jerome seems to have taken μέλλει as an impersonal verb ("it will come about that Herod..."), but this is not a possible interpretation of the Greek text as it stands. Maybe his manuscript had the accusative Ἡρῴδην?

Comment: Why is it not a possible interpretation? It's just a syntactic recasting: "Herod is going to..." --> "It is going to happen that Herod..." In Classical Greek μέλλει cannot, I believe, be used impersonally with an acc.+inf. construction, though I don't know about the Greek of the Septuagint.

Comment: @TKR. The subject of the infinitive ζητεῖν would need to be in the accusative, not the nominative, even in koine.

Comment: Right, but Ἡρῴδης is the subject of μέλλει, not of ζητεῖν. I'm not sure why you see a problem with Jerome's translation.

Comment: I do not see how μέλλει Ἡρῴδης can mean "futurum est ut Herodes..."

Comment: The syntax is different but the meaning is the same. Greek: "Herod is going to / will seek the child." Latin: "It will happen / is going to happen that Herod seeks the child." μέλλει does not necessarily mean "be on the point of" -- it can have a broader meaning of "be going to (at some unspecified point in the future)".

Comment: Fair enough. It is just that Bible translations are normally as literal as possible.

Comment: That's true. Maybe Jerome just didn't have a better option -- I don't think there's a common Latin verb that works exactly like μέλλω, and using a plain future wouldn't have been any more faithful to the original.

Comment: I [can't find a reading with accusative Ἡρῴδην](http://greeknewtestament.net/mt2-13): I checked a few places where μέλλει occurs in the NT and most times μέλλει + infinitive is translated into Latin as fut. act. part. + est. "mellei paschein" = "passurus est". One possible reason for this translation is that *quaesiturus* sounds awkward, but maybe that's just my ear.